# Unifrom Convergence and the weierstrass M test

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{{1+n^{2}x^{2}}}$ on the interval x $\in$ [1,$\infty$]

I tied to apply weierstrass m test but i didn't find any Series that R = $\infty$
how can i apply weierstass m test here , i need a series that Have R = $\infty$ so  the interval of Convergence = all the Reals, or is there another way?

Comment: This is not a power series, so the radius of convergence is not defined. Note for example that for $x=0$ the series does not converge, however the series is convergent in $[1, + \infty )$

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\frac1{1+n^2x^2}\le\frac{1}{1+n^2},\quad\forall x\ge1$$
and the series $\sum \frac{1}{1+n^2}$ is convergent. Conclude.